# iPhone Active Image

Tags: iphone, image-manipulation

I am trying to create an active image, similar to an image map but capable of zooming in and out using iPhone SDK

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a UIScrollView containing a UIImageView and with clickable areas implemented with UIButtons in "custom" mode.